# How do I find the registration or serial number for the aircraft I flew on specific trips in the past?

Tags: aircraft-registration

I understand that there are various [paid subscription services](https://www.flightradar24.com/premium/?change=true) that allow me to search back up to a year in the past for the IDs of any flight and the histories of any aircraft.

Is there a free (or one-time fee) service or API for identifying the aircraft I've flown on specific dates and flights in the (up to several years) past?

Comment: I think FlightAware has historical data, but it is a subscription service.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Yes, that's what the question says.

Comment: You linked FlightRadar, I mentioned FlightAware, two different services...

Comment: @RonBeyer: "various" and "is there a *free* (or one-time fee)...".

Comment: It's a one-time fee if you cancel the subscription right away...

Comment: @RonBeyer: That's not really the question, is it.

Comment: Excuse me, _Who_ is asking? :)

Comment: For specific dates and flights you might be able to get this question answered on a local aviation forum. At least in the Netherlands I know various examples of people who wanted more information about flights up to twenty years ago and got answered by people who had flight logs or other information for a specific day.

Answer (score 1):

The US (if that's your area of flying) is very kind in publicly [releasing stats](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/33622/14897) compared to other territories, but the answer is still you can't without a paid service.

See:

- [Where can I get information on ATC facility activity, like the number of flights handled in a month?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/where-can-i-get-information-on-atc-facility-activity-like-the-number-of-flights)
- [How can I get historic flight data by N-number?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33085/how-can-i-get-historic-flight-data-by-n-number)

In short: The FAA only keeps broad records that do not contain information such as tail numbers.

Start a personal flight journal for future flights, it's a hobby some enjoy. I did at one time, and when I couldn't catch the registration, I asked the flight crew.